# Error 406 during communication Android client with Ruby Rails server using POST

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, http, post

it's my first question. I and my friend have problem with communication between Android phone and ruby on rails server. I have two classes to communicate, one is only sending data to server and that one is working correctly, but the second which is sending and receiving data is giving exception for error 406. Everything is working at LAN network. If i delete exception for error 406 in logs i can find java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.0.104:3000/moments/send_status

below is the code of class:

```
 private class WebServiceOdbierz extends  AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    // okienko dialogowe, które każe użytkownikowi czekać
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    // metoda wykonywana jest zaraz przed główną operacją (doInBackground())
    // mamy w niej dostęp do elementów UI
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // wyświetlamy okienko dialogowe każące czekać
        dialog.setMessage("Czekaj...");
        dialog.show();

    }

    // główna operacja, która wykona się w osobnym wątku
    // nie ma w niej dostępu do elementów UI
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            // zakładamy, że jest tylko jeden URL
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // timeout w ms
            connection.setReadTimeout(3000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(4000);
            // zezwolenie na wysyłanie danych
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            // ustawienie typu wysyłanych danych
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;");
            //ustawienie metody
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // stworzenie obiektu do wysłania
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("zrodlo",zrodlo);
            data.put("wartosc", "wszystko");
            data.put("moment", "100");

            //if(tryb == "true") {

            // wysłanie obiektu
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),
                            "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data.toString());
            writer.close();

            // }

            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // na tym etapie obiekt został wysłany
            // i dostaliśmy odpowiedź serwera
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == 406) {
                throw new Exception("blad 406");
            }

            // sprawdzenie kodu odpowiedzi, 200 = OK


            // pobranie danych do InputStream
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    connection.getInputStream());

            // konwersja InputStream na String
            // wynik będzie przekazany do metody onPostExecute()
            return streamToString(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // obsłuż wyjątek
            Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), e.toString());
            return null;
        }

    }

    // metoda wykonuje się po zakończeniu metody głównej,
    // której wynik będzie przekazany;
    // w tej metodzie mamy dostęp do UI
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // chowamy okno dialogowe
        dialog.dismiss();
        //////////////////////////////////////////// ODBIOR DANYCH
        try {


            // reprezentacja obiektu JSON w Javie
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

            //trybRec = json.optString("tryb");
            Temperatura = json.optString("Temperatura");
            CO2 = json.optString("CO2");
            Swiatlo = json.optString("Swiatlo");
            Wilgotnosc = json.optString("Wilgotnosc");
            Lampy = json.optString("Lampy");
            Ogrzewanie = json.optString("Grzejniki");
            Pompa = json.optString("Pompa");
            Rolety = json.optString("Rolety");
            zaworCO2 = json.optString("ZaworCO2");
            // Jak będzie komunikacja działać
            updateLedsAndText();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // obsłuż wyjątek
            Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried to change POST to GET but without effect
And below the code of working one:

```
    private class WebServiceWyslij extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // okienko dialogowe, które każe użytkownikowi czekać
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    // metoda wykonywana jest zaraz przed główną operacją (doInBackground())
    // mamy w niej dostęp do elementów UI
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // wyświetlamy okienko dialogowe każące czekać
        dialog.setMessage("Czekaj...");
        dialog.show();

    }

    // główna operacja, która wykona się w osobnym wątku
    // nie ma w niej dostępu do elementów UI
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            // zakładamy, że jest tylko jeden URL
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // timeout w ms

            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
            // zezwolenie na wysyłanie danych
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            // ustawienie typu wysyłanych danych
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;");
            //ustawienie metody
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // stworzenie obiektu do wysłania
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("zrodlo",zrodlo);

            data.put("tryb",tryb);
            /*
            data.put("Temperatura", Temperatura);
            data.put("CO2", CO2);
            data.put("Światło", Swiatlo);
            data.put("Wilgotność", Wilgotnosc);
            */

            data.put("moment","2016-01-01 12:00:00");
            data.put("Lampy", Lampy);
            data.put("Rolety", Rolety);
            data.put("Grzejniki", Ogrzewanie);
            data.put("Pompa", Pompa);
            data.put("ZaworCO2", zaworCO2);


                // wysłanie obiektu
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),
                                "UTF-8"));


                writer.write(data.toString());
                writer.close();



            //////////////////////////////////////////
            // na tym etapie obiekt został wysłany
            // i dostaliśmy odpowiedź serwera
            //////////////////////////////////////////

            // sprawdzenie kodu odpowiedzi, 200 = OK
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new Exception("Bad Request");
            }



            // pobranie danych do InputStream
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    connection.getInputStream());

            // konwersja InputStream na String
            // wynik będzie przekazany do metody onPostExecute()
            if(!(streamToString(in).length()>0)){
                throw new Exception("odebrales pustego stringa");
            }
            return streamToString(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // obsłuż wyjątek
            Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), e.toString());
            return null;
        }

    }

    // metoda wykonuje się po zakończeniu metody głównej,
    // której wynik będzie przekazany;
    // w tej metodzie mamy dostęp do UI
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // chowamy okno dialogowe
        dialog.dismiss();
        //////////////////////////////////////////// ODBIOR DANYCH
        try {
            // reprezentacja obiektu JSON w Javie
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // obsłuż wyjątek
            Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

to your POST after setting `Content-Type`?

Comment: Adding 'connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;"); 'doesn't help, there's still  406 response code

Comment: connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); -- without semicolon afer "json".

Comment: Great ;-) Remove the semicolon from Content-Type header too.